# Is there any way to tell if there is a miner (in a pool) on the network, from a network perspective?

Tags: mining-pools, security, network

I'm thinking traffic analysis, packet inspection, IP.

How would that be differenciable from other traffic patterns?

How active do admins look for such patterns?(I'm thinking more P2P stuff)

Comment: `I'm thinking more P2P stuff` AFAIK, pooled miners don't produce any P2P traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pool miners connect to the pool server, not to the P2P network. You may be able to find the pool server by tracing the origin of the blocks, but you can't find the individual pooled miners on the network, as they're not actually on the network.

Comment: How much data gets passed trough the network from the mining PC? Can they look at the protocol as it is very specific?

Comment: The stratum/getwork 'protocols' can easily be identified as such, yeah. The amount of data passed between the pool server and miner is minimal: iirc the miner only needs 80 bytes of the block it's creating.